# Split string in Powershell

Tags: powershell, split

I have sth written in a ".ini" file that i want to read from PS. The file gives the value "notepad.exe" and i want to give the value "notepad" into a variable. So i do the following:

```
$CLREXE = Get-Content -Path "T:\keeran\Test-kill\test.ini" | Select-String -Pattern 'CLREXE'
#split the value from "CLREXE ="
$CLREXE = $CLREXE -split "="
#everything fine untill here
$CLREXE = $CLREXE[1]
#i am trying to omit ".exe" here. But it doesn't work
$d = $CLREXE -split "." | Select-String -NotMatch 'exe'
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: `-split` is a regex operator, you need to escape `.`: `$CLREXE -split '\.'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-split` is a [regex operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions), and `.` is a special metacharacter in regex - so you need to escape it:

```
$CLREXE -split '\.'
```

A better way would be to use the `-replace` operator to remove the last `.` and everything after it:

```
$CLREXE -replace '\.[^\.]+$'
```

The regex pattern matches one literal dot (`\.`), then 1 or more non-dots (`[^\.]+`) followed by the end of the string `$`.

---

If you're not comfortable with regular expressions, you can also use .NET's native string methods for this:

```
$CLREXE.Remove($CLREXE.LastIndexOf('.'))
```

Here, we use `String.LastIndexOf` to locate the index (the position in the string) of the last occurrence of `.`, then removing anything from there on out

Comment: Thanks +1! This really answer the OP!

Answer (score 4):

@Mathias R. Jessen is already answered your question.

But instead of splitting on filename you could use the [`GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?view=net-5.0#System_IO_Path_GetFileNameWithoutExtension_System_String_) method from [.NET Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=net-5.0)  class.

```
$CLREXE = "notepad.exe"
$fileNameWithoutExtension = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($CLREXE) 
Write-Host $fileNameWithoutExtension  # this will print just 'notepad'
```

Comment: This is in my opinion a more stable and generic solution as a filename actually could contain more than one '.' in the name...